# evaluation of a string variable with another string doesn't evaluate. ASP CLASSIC

Tags: variables, types, asp-classic, eval, evaluation

i have a series of big forms, in many pages, so i have done some functions that should populate the form fields when someone update the page, the situation is like this:

```
 <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="imm_AriaCondizionata" value="s" <%=richecca("imm_AriaCondizionata","s")%>>Si </label>
 <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" name="imm_AriaCondizionata" value="n" <%=richecca("imm_AriaCondizionata","n")%>>No </label>


function richecca(NomeCampo,sino)           
    if request(NomeCampo) <> "" then        
        if request(Nomecampo) = sino then 
            richecca = " checked "
        else
            richecca = ""
        end if
    else
        if eval(NomeCampo) = sino then
            richecca = " checked "
        else
            richecca = ""
        end if
    end if

end function
```

so, it checks if there is some values on the request(both formand querystring) and if nothing is there, it checks a variable with a name passed to the function.

the problem is, even if i put the value in the variable, it always take the "else" branch. how is it possible...is it evaluating the sting as another type?
i mean:

```
Dim imm_AriaCondizionata = "n"
richecca("imm_AriaCondizionata","n")
```

it returns "" of the second else so the one:

```
if eval(NomeCampo) = sino then
    richecca = " checked "
else
    richecca = ""
end if
```

here if i write a response.write(eval(NomeCampo) ) and response.write(sino) i have booth of them with a value of "n"... i'm becoming mad on this...how is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if strcomp(eval(NomeCampo),sino,1) = 0 then
richecca = " checked "
else
    richecca = ""
end if
```

i finally found this strcomp!!! that make a comparision binary or textual of two variables!

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_strcomp.asp
here the article. :D
thanks